# checking if owner/group match in files and subfolders

Tags: file, shell, permissions, directory

I need help on writing a shell script to check if the owner and group matches the names I have in my IF statement. It needs to recursively check all files and folders, including the parent folder.

For example, my directory structure might look like this

```
/data
/data/folder1
/data/folder1/fileA
/data/folder2/fileB
```

I need to verify that data, folder1, folder2, fileA, fileB are all owned by the same owner and group.

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR="/data";
N=0;

for $DIR..
  if [ NOT MATCH "username:groupname" ]; then
    N=1;
  fi
done

if [ $N -gt 0 ]; then
  echo "all or some files and folders don't match";
else 
  echo "all files match";
fi
```

Comment: what is `NOT MATCH`?

Comment: and do you have to use recursion?

Comment: Yes, recursion is required however its only 1 or 2 directories deep and contains no more than 50 files so it should be a fairly quick process.

Comment: but i dont see any recursion

Comment: That's what I need help with...

Comment: take a look at what i put

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
OWNER=user
ACTUAL_OWNER='stat -c %U file' 
N=0;

   not_match(files)
  {
      if [ ! OWNER = ACTUAL_OWNER ]; then
        N=1;
        return;
      else if [ not_end_of_file ]; then
        not_match(files+1)
      else 
        return
      fi
  }

    DIR="/data";
    not_match(files)
    if [ $N -gt 0 ]; then
      echo "all or some files and folders don't match";
    else 
      echo "all files match";
    fi
```

i wasnt sure of some of the exact commands or syntax so it has some sudo code but it is basically what you want to do. if they are a match and its not the end of the files you are searching call the function again and increase to the next file if it doesnt match say they dont and just return since you dont tell the user how many dont match and if the end is reached then success and return to print out to the user

Comment: I will give this a try tomorrow. Thanks!